# Loading time storyboard controller is very long

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have very complicated UIViewController in Storyboard. This UIViewController have UITableView with two scrollview in cells,two others UIView, five UIImageView and some UILabels. 
First time when user would see this controller time is about ~5s, next times is very fast ~0.5s.

The lag is between viewWillApper and viewDidApper in lifecycle controller.

How can I optimise this view UIViewController?

Comment: Profile the app in instruments using the Time Profiler. This will tell you exactly where it is being slow (down to the line of code). Without seeing any code there is nothing we can do.

Comment: Is it your Root View Controller?

Comment: this is no root view controller. How can I read Time Profiler? Order by running time and analyze?

Comment: The problem line is:   DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder *stringBuilder = [[DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder alloc] initWithHTML:data
                                                                                               options:builderOptions
                                                                                    documentAttributes:nil]; cell.dtAttrTV.attributedString = [stringBuilder generatedAttributedString];

Comment: ok. Content(or data) in UITableView & UIScrollView and images in UIImageView is loading locally or from web services?

Comment: web services, but all is loading asynchrous

Comment: ok when i Use     dispatch_async for generatedAttributedString everything is ok, but why only first time loading is so long?

Comment: I cant use dispatch_async because I need it in ui thread for calculate cell height ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found my problem:

```
DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder *stringBuilder = [[DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder alloc] initWithHTML:data
                                                                                           options:builderOptions
                                                                                documentAttributes:nil];

NSAttributedString *attrString = [stringBuilder generatedAttributedString];
```

generatedAttributedString generated lag. I found this problem by Time Profiler ( thanks for Fogmeister).

So i remove this problem by generate fake content before initialize viewcontroller:

```
    NSString *html = @"<html>fake content</html>";
NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *builderOptions = @{
                                 DTDefaultFontFamily: @"Helvetica",
                                 DTDefaultFontSize: @14
                                 };
DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder *stringBuilder = [[DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder alloc] initWithHTML:data
                                                                                           options:builderOptions
                                                                                documentAttributes:nil];



NSAttributedString *attrString = [stringBuilder generatedAttributedString];
Zlog(@"attrString %@", attrString);
```